# Sorting Elasticsearch Results After Scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query like the one above. I am trying to sort it by created_at date in descending order AFTER the results are scored meaning that the sorting has no effect on what is returned only the order.

When I use the sort array, it effects the results returned. How do I remedy this? Thank you!!!

```
 array:3 [▼
     "index" => "quotes"
     "type" => "quote"
  "body" => array:5 [▼
    "from" => 0
    "size" => 50
    "min_score" => 0
    "query" => array:1 [▼
      "function_score" => array:1 [▼
        "query" => array:1 [▼
          "bool" => array:4 [▼
            "filter" => array:1 [▼
              0 => array:1 [▼
                "term" => array:1 [▼
                  "value_proposition" => "encouraging"
                ]
              ]
            ]
            "must_not" => array:3 [▼
              0 => array:1 [▼
                0 => array:1 [▼
                  "term" => array:1 [▼
                    "explicit" => "1"
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              1 => array:1 [▼
                0 => array:1 [▼
                  "term" => array:1 [▼
                    "explicit" => "1"
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              2 => array:1 [▼
                0 => array:1 [▼
                  "term" => array:1 [▼
                    "value_duration" => "ephemeral"
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
            "must" => []
            "should" => array:18 [▶]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "sort" => []
  ]
]
```

Comment: Sort should not alter the results nor the scores. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html Can you elaborate in what way the result is changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

Elasticsearch isn't the best tool for this so I wound up using PHP's native sorting methods namely `usort` to sort by likes AFTER Elasticsearch returned it's results. One thing to note however, performance was significantly increased by separating out the sorting function from usort. I.e. I didn't use usort as a higher order function, defined the function above and passed the name in as a string.